# JavaFX Text message not displayed

Tags: javafx

```
stage = primaryStage;
Text message = new Text();
pane1 = new GridPane();
pane1.add(message, 0, 0);
scene1 = new Scene(pane1); 
//scene2 is built and similar to scene.
if (getAns() == false) {
    message.setText("Wrong");
    stage.setScene(scene1);
} else {
    message.setText("Correct");
    stage.setScene(scene2);
}
stage.setTitle("Test");
stage.show();
```

When getAns() is true, message is displayed. When getAns() is false, message is not displayed, why?

Comment: `message` is displayed in `scene1`. So if you display `scene2`, you can't see it. (It can't be in two different scenes.)

Comment: Okay I got it. Thanks James_D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

message is displayed in scene1. So if you display scene2, you can't see it. (It can't be in two different scenes.) – James_D Oct 4 at 15:41